# Raspberry Pi phpmyadmin showing source code instead of actual interface

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, raspberry-pi

I recently got myself a RaspberryPi B+ and wanted to create a webserver to host a database. I followed a few tutorials all went fine until I tried to access it with 192.168.2.x/phpmyadmin. It showed me this instead of the interface:

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * forms frameset
 *
 * @uses    $GLOBALS['cfg']['QueryHistoryDB']
 * @uses    $GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['user']
 * @uses    $GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultTabServer']     as src for the mainframe
 * @uses    $GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultTabDatabase']   as src for the mainframe
 * @uses    $GLOBALS['cfg']['NaviWidth']            for navi frame width
 * @uses    $GLOBALS['collation_connection']    from $_REQUEST (grab_globals.lib.php)
 *                                              or common.inc.php
 * @uses    $GLOBALS['available_languages'] from common.inc.php (select_lang.lib.php)
 * @uses    $GLOBALS['db']
 * @uses    $GLOBALS['charset']
 * @uses    $GLOBALS['lang']
 * @uses    $GLOBALS['text_dir']
 * @uses    $_ENV['HTTP_HOST']
 * @uses    PMA_getRelationsParam()
 * @uses    PMA_purgeHistory()
 * @uses    PMA_generate_common_url()
 * @uses    PMA_VERSION
 * @uses    session_write_close()
 * @uses    time()
 * @uses    PMA_getenv()
 * @uses    header()                to send charset
 * @package phpMyAdmin
 */

/**
 * Gets core libraries and defines some variables
 */
require_once './libraries/common.inc.php';

// free the session file, for the other frames to be loaded
session_write_close();

// Gets the host name
if (empty($HTTP_HOST)) {
    if (PMA_getenv('HTTP_HOST')) {
        $HTTP_HOST = PMA_getenv('HTTP_HOST');
    } else {
        $HTTP_HOST = '';
    }
}


// purge querywindow history
$cfgRelation = PMA_getRelationsParam();
if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['QueryHistoryDB'] && $cfgRelation['historywork']) {
    PMA_purgeHistory($GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['user']);
}
unset($cfgRelation);


/**
 * pass variables to child pages
 */
$drops = array('lang', 'server', 'collation_connection',
    'db', 'table');

foreach ($drops as $each_drop) {
    if (array_key_exists($each_drop, $_GET)) {
        unset($_GET[$each_drop]);
    }
}
unset($drops, $each_drop);

if (! strlen($GLOBALS['db'])) {
    $main_target = $GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultTabServer'];
} elseif (! strlen($GLOBALS['table'])) {
    $_GET['db'] = $GLOBALS['db'];
    $main_target = $GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultTabDatabase'];
} else {
    $_GET['db'] = $GLOBALS['db'];
    $_GET['table'] = $GLOBALS['table'];
    $main_target = $GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultTabTable'];
}

$url_query = PMA_generate_common_url($_GET);

if (isset($GLOBALS['target']) && is_string($GLOBALS['target']) && !empty($GLOBALS['target']) && in_array($GLOBALS['target'], $goto_whitelist)) {
    $main_target = $GLOBALS['target'];
}

$main_target .= $url_query;

$lang_iso_code = $GLOBALS['available_languages'][$GLOBALS['lang']][1];


// start output
include ('./libraries/header_http.inc.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xml:lang="<?php echo $lang_iso_code; ?>"
    lang="<?php echo $lang_iso_code; ?>"
    dir="<?php echo $GLOBALS['text_dir']; ?>">
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<title>phpMyAdmin <?php echo PMA_VERSION; ?> -
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($HTTP_HOST); ?></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=<?php echo $GLOBALS['charset']; ?>" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    // definitions used in common.js
    var common_query = '<?php echo PMA_escapeJsString(PMA_generate_common_url('', '', '&'));?>';
    var opendb_url = '<?php echo PMA_escapeJsString($GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultTabDatabase']); ?>';
    var safari_browser = <?php echo PMA_USR_BROWSER_AGENT == 'SAFARI' ? 'true' : 'false' ?>;
    var querywindow_height = <?php echo PMA_escapeJsString($GLOBALS['cfg']['QueryWindowHeight']); ?>;
    var querywindow_width = <?php echo PMA_escapeJsString($GLOBALS['cfg']['QueryWindowWidth']); ?>;
    var collation_connection = '<?php echo PMA_escapeJsString($GLOBALS['collation_connection']); ?>';
    var lang = '<?php echo PMA_escapeJsString($GLOBALS['lang']); ?>';
    var server = '<?php echo PMA_escapeJsString($GLOBALS['server']); ?>';
    var table = '<?php echo PMA_escapeJsString($GLOBALS['table']); ?>';
    var db    = '<?php echo PMA_escapeJsString($GLOBALS['db']); ?>';
    var token = '<?php echo PMA_escapeJsString($_SESSION[' PMA_token ']); ?>';
    var text_dir = '<?php echo PMA_escapeJsString($GLOBALS['text_dir']); ?>';
    var pma_absolute_uri = '<?php echo PMA_escapeJsString($GLOBALS['cfg']['PmaAbsoluteUri']); ?>';
    var pma_text_default_tab = '<?php echo PMA_escapeJsString(PMA_getTitleForTarget($GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultTabTable'])); ?>';
    var pma_text_left_default_tab = '<?php echo PMA_escapeJsString(PMA_getTitleForTarget($GLOBALS['cfg']['LeftDefaultTabTable'])); ?>';

    // for content and navigation frames

    var frame_content = 0;
    var frame_navigation = 0;
    function getFrames() {
<?php if ($GLOBALS['text_dir'] === 'ltr') { ?>
        frame_content = window.frames[1];
        frame_navigation = window.frames[0];
<?php } else { ?>
        frame_content = window.frames[0];
        frame_navigation = window.frames[1];
<?php } ?>
    }
    var onloadCnt = 0;
    var onLoadHandler = window.onload;
    window.onload = function() {
        if (onloadCnt == 0) {
            if (typeof(onLoadHandler) == "function") {
                onLoadHandler();
            }
            if (typeof(getFrames) != 'undefined' && typeof(getFrames) == 'function') {
                getFrames();
            }
            onloadCnt++;
        }
    };
// ]]>
</script>
<?php
echo PMA_includeJS('jquery/jquery-1.4.4.js');
echo PMA_includeJS('update-location.js');
echo PMA_includeJS('common.js');
?>
</head>
<frameset cols="<?php
if ($GLOBALS['text_dir'] === 'rtl') {
    echo '*,';
}
echo $GLOBALS['cfg']['NaviWidth'];
if ($GLOBALS['text_dir'] === 'ltr') {
    echo ',*';
}
?>" rows="*" id="mainFrameset">
    <?php if ($GLOBALS['text_dir'] === 'ltr') { ?>
    <frame frameborder="0" id="frame_navigation"
        src="navigation.php<?php echo $url_query; ?>"
        name="frame_navigation" />
    <?php } ?>
    <frame frameborder="0" id="frame_content"
        src="<?php echo $main_target; ?>"
        name="frame_content" />
    <?php if ($GLOBALS['text_dir'] === 'rtl') { ?>
    <frame frameborder="0" id="frame_navigation"
        src="navigation.php<?php echo $url_query; ?>"
        name="frame_navigation" />
    <?php } ?>
    <noframes>
        <body>
            <p><?php echo __('phpMyAdmin is more friendly with a <b>frames-capable</b> browser.'); ?></p>
        </body>
    </noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

I have tried fixing it by checking configs etc, googled the problem as well but couldnt find anything that solved this issue. Heres one of the tutorials I used: https://www.anavi.org/article/163/

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is a sign you haven't:

- Loaded the PHP module.
- Configured `.php` files to be handled by the PHP module.

Be sure that there's an `AddHandler` directive somewhere in your configuration files. Otherwise the server sees these as just plain text files.

Answer (score 0):

What web server you are serving this with? How does php gets the file?

A good way on a Pi is Nginx whith a proxy for the php files to php-fastcgi. Right now you are using Apache and you likely do not have php setup at all and only a bare web server that sends the php files as-is, which is the normal behavior.

In short : You need to configure your webserver (Apache in you case) so that it recognizes the php files and sends them to PHP. Otherwise the PHP is not interpreted and you get raw source code.

Comment: I am using Apache as webserver, it also asked me if I wanted to use this webserver when setting up phpmyadmin. I enabled this by making sure the asterics was in there and then pressed ok. Any idea on how I could make apache recognize php files?

Comment: See tadman's answer. I never configured Apache with PHP. I would have gone with a ProxyPass to php-cgi but tadman seems to know better.